# Sails js adapter not able to get connection due to poolsize

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql, max-pool-size

Sails js adapter is not able to get connection due to poolsize, i think increasing poolsize should solve the problem, anyone else faced this and how you fixed it.
Getting below error
`Unexpected error from database adapter:`select`failed (\"badConnection\").  A connection either could not be obtained or there was an error using the connection.\nAdditional data:\n\n{\n  error: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN`

Increased the sails version, it didn't help.